# Titanic - loops to get names

Tags: r

I'm using the titanic dataset to get the list the children's names, aged 14 or under, on the Titanic. I'm not sure how to get the corresponding Children's name if they are under 14 from the titanic dataset.

```
titanic <- read.csv(file = "http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/pub/Main/DataSets/titanic3.csv", stringsAsFactors = F)

#1
a <- character()
for (i in titanicDataset$V5) {
    if (i < 14) {
    print(titanicDataset$name)
    }
    else {
    }
}
titanicDataset$age <- a
```

Answer (score 1):

```
under14 <- subset(x = titanic,
                  age <= 14)$name

under14

[1] "Allison, Master. Hudson Trevor"                    "Allison, Miss. Helen Loraine"                      "Carter, Master. William Thornton II"              
  [4] "Carter, Miss. Lucile Polk"                         "Dodge, Master. Washington"                         "Ryerson, Master. John Borie"                      
  [7] "Spedden, Master. Robert Douglas"                   "Becker, Master. Richard F"                         "Becker, Miss. Marion Louise"                      
 [10] "Becker, Miss. Ruth Elizabeth"                      "Caldwell, Master. Alden Gates"                     "Collyer, Miss. Marjorie \"Lottie\""               
 [13] "Davies, Master. John Morgan Jr"                    "Drew, Master. Marshall Brines"                     "Hamalainen, Master. Viljo"                        
 [16] "Harper, Miss. Annie Jessie \"Nina\""               "Hart, Miss. Eva Miriam"                            "Laroche, Miss. Louise"                         

[...]
```

---

And a for loop version, as requested:

```
a <- character()

for (row in 1:nrow(titanic)){ # iterate over the rows in the dataframe, not the ages like in the for loop you tried
  if (titanic[row, "age"] <= 14 & !is.na(titanic[row, "age"])) {
  # if the age value in a row is less than or equal to 14 and not NA, add the name from that row to "a"
    a <- c(a, titanic[row, "name"])
  } else { # if not, do nothing

  }
}

all.equal(a, under14) # confirm "a" and "under14" are identical

[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Hey thank you. While this worked, I'm trying to use an for-loop and if statement to get it. Do you know how? @Eugene Chong

Comment: See updated answer.  I'm guessing this is a homework assignment, which is why you want the for loop and if statement, but be aware for the future that the first solution will be orders of magnitude faster than the loop.